# WinForms, set Input cursor after Text.Replace at the end of text

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I'm currently writing a tiny finance-related application and want to make sure that my users KNOW how to write a decimal value (with a DOT instead of a COMMA.)

To make sure that the input is correct I've submitted the control to the TextChanged event as follows.

```
        // Remove people not knowing how to write decimals.
        if (ExpenseValueTB.Text.Contains(',')) {
            ExpenseValueTB.Text = ExpenseValueTB.Text.Replace(',', '.');
            ExpenseValueTB.Focus();
        }
```

Now this definitely works, but unfortunately the input cursor jumps back to the beginning. So if someone wanted to write '15,96', they end up writing 9615.

I've looked around but any other similar issues were js or PHP

Many thanks!

Comment: Please note, user may want to enter 123,45.67, so not every Comma should be replaced by a dot.

Comment: Thanks Bolu, that's right. Although my program is for managing small household expenses. I should think about it though for future implementations. Basically I should only allow one dot, as the floating point divider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [SelectionStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart.aspx) and [SelectionLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionlength.aspx) from the TextBox base methods

```
    if (ExpenseValueTB.Text.Contains(',')) {
        ExpenseValueTB.Text = ExpenseValueTB.Text.Replace(',', '.');
        ExpenseValueTB.SelectionStart = ExpenseValueTB.Text.IndexOf('.') + 1;
        ExpenseValueTB.SelectionLength = 0;
        ExpenseValueTB.Focus();
    }
```

but probably your best approach is to remove the simple TextBox and use a MaskedTextBox that allows you to better format the user input

Comment: also, thanks for the suggestion of using MaskedTextBox, I'll consider it.

Answer (score 1):

Is that what are you looking for?

```
ExpenseValueTB.SelectionStart = ExpenseValueTB.Text.Length;
```

Comment: Thanks aef, you were out-answered though :)